# Global generation of restricted tangent and cotangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ be a smooth projective variety. Consider the following restricted and twisted Euler exact sequence given by :

$0 \to \Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X}(2) \to \mathcal O_X^{\oplus n+1}(1) \to \mathcal O_X(2) \to 0$

Can we say that $\Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X}(2)$ is globally generated?

Taking dual of the above sequence one can show that $T_{\mathbb P^n}|{X}(-1)$ is globally generated. Is the global generation of $\Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X}(2)$  related to that?

Also if some $T_{\mathbb P^n}|{X}(k)$ is globally generated, is it the case that $k \leq -1$? (this seems confusing as tensoring with $\mathcal O_X(1)$ many times should keep it globally generated and hence $k$ should be $\geq -1$)

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=H^0(O_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1))$. Then you have the Koszul exact sequence,
$$0\to \wedge^{n+1}(-n-1)\to \cdots \to \wedge^2 V(-2)\to V(-1)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to 0$$

This shows that $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2)$ is globally generated.

Comment: do you mean $V^*(1)$ is same as $\mathcal O(1)^{\oplus h^0(\mathcal O(1)}$ (over $\mathbb P^n$)? In that case we can write that koszul sequence as $\mathcal O(1)^{\oplus h^0(\mathcal O(1)}$ is globally generated and hence has a regular section right? But why that exact sequence gives us  $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n}(2)$ is globally generated? I can see that it is the kernel of the map from $\mathcal O(1)^{\oplus h^0(\mathcal O(1)}$  to $\mathcal O(2)$. I s the kernel automatically globally generated? and finally is it trivial that the restriction of a globally generated bundle is so?

Comment: @Sherlock The exactness of Koszul complex says, a bunch of $O(-2)$ maps onto $\Omega^1$ and twisting by $O(2)$ gives global generation of $\Omega^1(2)$. For your last question, if $F\to G$ is onto, restriction to a subvariety is onto, since tensor product is right exact.